# Как показать записи, где стоимость меньше либо равна 100?

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM it_catalog_index WHERE PRICE <= 100 ORDER BY RAITING_TOTAL DESC LIMIT 0 , 9000

PRICE int(11)
```

Не срабатывает вообще, выводит все записи.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `it_catalog_index` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'restaurant ID',
  `ACTIVE` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `NAME` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'or dish name',
  `ADDRESS` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'address',
  `CITY` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'city name',
  `METRO` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'metro station name',
  `METRO_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'id metro station',
  `TYPE` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'type name',
  `CITY_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'restaurant city ID',
  `TYPE_ID` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'restaurant type ID',
  `COUNTRY_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'restaurant country ID',
  `DELIVERY` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'restaurant delivery - 1 if true, 0 if false',
  `PRICE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'price for delivery service',
  `DELIVERY_TIME` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'delivery time',
  `DELIVERY_MIN_ORDER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'minimal order summ for a delivery service',
  `RAITING_TOTAL` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'reiting',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `COUNTRY_ID` (`CITY_ID`,`COUNTRY_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Grammar nazi comment: поле `RAITING_TOTAL` явно добавлял прогер без языка. Целых два варианта неправильного написания слова "рейтинг" ("rating"): само поле, и коммент )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм.. А зачем Вы пишите `LIMIT`?

Не знаю, с виду не вижу ничего неправильного. Единственное, можно попробовать:

```
SELECT * FROM `it_catalog_index` WHERE `PRICE` <= 100 ORDER BY `RAITING_TOTAL` DESC
```

Comment:     ORDER BY `RAITING_TOTAL DESC`

А тут с кавычками не переборщили? Скажет, ведь, что не найден такой столбец

Comment: я пока тестирую, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: переборщил, 

     SELECT * FROM `it_catalog_index` WHERE `PRICE` <= 100 ORDER BY `RAITING_TOTAL` DESC

Answer (score 0):

Оператор <= в MySQL есть, и проблема явно не в нем. Таблицу в студию

Comment: добавил таблицу

Comment: У меня тоже все работает, mysql 5.1.46

Answer (score 0):

Запрос для данной таблицы исправно работает, проверил в MySql 5.5.25 под виндоус, скорей всего не в запросе дело.